# How to access a PSDrive from System.IO.File calls?

Tags: c#, powershell, new-psdrive

I'm writing a c# cmdlet which copies files from one location to another (similar to rsync).   It even supports ToSession and FromSession.

I'd like it to work with PSDrives that use the Filesystem provider but it currently throws an error from System.IO.File.GetAttributes("psdrive:\path")

I'd really like to use calls from System.IO on the PSDrive.

How does something like copy-item do this?

I've performed a search for accessing PSDrives from c# and have returned no results.

This is the equivalent of my code

```
new-psdrive -name mydrive -psprovider filesystem  -root \\aserver\ashare -Credential domain\user
$attributes=[system.io.file]::GetAttributes("mydrive:\path\")
```

returns

```
Exception calling "GetAttributes" with "1" argument(s): "The given path's format is not supported."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**.NET knows nothing about *PowerShell* drives** (and typically also has a different working directory), so **conversion to a *filesystem-native* path is necessary**:

**In PowerShell code**:

Use [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) to convert a PowerShell-drive-based path to a native filesystem path that .NET types understand:

```bash
$attributes=[System.IO.File]::GetAttributes((Convert-Path "mydrive:\path\"))
```

By default (positional argument use) and with `-Path`, `Convert-Path` performs wildcard resolution; to suppress the latter, use the `-LiteralPath` parameter.

**Caveat**: `Convert-Path` only works with *existing* paths. Lifting that restriction is the subject of the feature request in [GitHub issue #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993).

---

**In C# code:**

In [`PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet)-derived cmdlets:

- Use [`GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.getunresolvedproviderpathfrompspath) to translate a PS-drive-based path into a native-drive-based path<sup>[1]</sup> *unresolved*, which means that, aside from translating the drive part:

  - the existence of the path is not verified (but the drive name must exist)
  - and *no* wildcard resolution is performed.
- Use [`GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.getresolvedproviderpathfrompspath) to *resolve* a PS-drive-based path to a native-drive-based one, which means that, aside from translating the drive part:

  - wildcard resolution *is* performed, yielding potentially multiple paths or even none.
  - literal path components *must exist*.
- Use the [`CurrentProviderLocation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.currentproviderlocation) method with provider ID `"FileSystem"` to get the current filesystem location's path as a `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` instance; that instance's `.Path` property and `.ToString()` method return the PS form of the path; use the `.ProviderPath` property to get the native representation.

Here's a simple ad-hoc compiled cmdlet that exercises both methods:

```bash
# Compiles a Get-NativePath cmdlet and adds it to the session.
Add-Type @'
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet("Get", "NativePath")]
    public class GetNativePathCommand : PSCmdlet {

        [Parameter(Mandatory=true,Position=0)]
        public string PSPath { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            WriteObject("Current directory:");
            WriteObject("  PS form:      " + CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem"));
            WriteObject("  Native form:  " + CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem").ProviderPath);
            //
            WriteObject("Path argument in native form:");
            WriteObject("  Unresolved:");
            WriteObject("    " + GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(PSPath));
            //
            WriteObject("  Resolved:");
            ProviderInfo pi;
            foreach (var p in GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(PSPath, out pi))
            {
              WriteObject("    " + p);
            }
        }
    }
'@ -PassThru | % Assembly | Import-Module
```

You can test it as follows:

```bash
# Create a foo: drive whose root is the current directory.
$null = New-PSDrive foo filesystem .

# Change to foo:
Push-Location foo:\

# Pass a wildcard path based on the new drive to the cmdlet
# and have it translated to a native path, both unresolved and resolved;
# also print the current directory, both in PS form and in native form.
Get-NativePath foo:\*.txt
```

If your current directory is `C:\Temp` and it happens to contain text files `a.txt` and `b.txt`, you'll see the following output:

```
Current directory:
  PS form:      foo:\
  Native form:  C:\Temp\
Path argument in native form:
  Unresolved:
    C:\Temp\*.txt
  Resolved:
    C:\Temp\a.txt
    C:\Temp\b.txt
```

---

<sup>[1] If a PS drive (created with `New-PSDrive`) referenced in the input path is defined in terms of a *UNC* path, the resulting native path will be a UNC path too.</sup>