# How to expand path in binary PowerShell module?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a simple sample binary PowerShell module:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace MyModule
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test,"SampleCmdlet")]
    [OutputType(typeof(System.String))]
    public class TestSampleCmdletCommand : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = true,
            Position = 0,
            ValueFromPipeline = true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        // This method gets called once for each cmdlet in the pipeline when the pipeline starts executing
        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            WriteVerbose("Begin!");
        }

        // This method will be called for each input received from the pipeline to this cmdlet; if no input is received, this method is not called
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject( Path );
            WriteObject( System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Path) );
        }

        // This method will be called once at the end of pipeline execution; if no input is received, this method is not called
        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            WriteVerbose("End!");
        }
    }

}
```

When I import the module and run the code, GetFullPath() always returns a path relative to the user profile and not the real full path:

```
PS C:\Users\User\GitHub\MyModule\source\MyModule> Import-Module -Name .\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyModule.dll
PS C:\Users\User\GitHub\MyModule\source\MyModule> cd \
PS C:\> Test-SampleCmdlet -Path .\Temp\
.\Temp\
C:\Users\User\Temp\
PS C:\>
```

How can I expand the path parameter properly?

Comment: What do you get when you display `Environment.CurrentDirectory` or `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.NET methods use the *process-wide* current directory as reflected in `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, which is *not* the same as PowerShell's *runspace-specific* (thread-specific) current location.**<sup>[1]</sup>

**You cannot directly rely on `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()`**, at least not without also specifying the runspace's current file-system location as the optional 2nd `basePath` argument - which is only available in .NET Core / PowerShell [Core] 6+.

**To robustly refer to the calling runspace's current *file-system* location**, even when a different provider's location happens to be the current one<sup>[2]</sup>, you can use **`.CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem").ProviderPath`** as follows in PowerShell [Core] 6+ / .NET Core (`Path` is the property representing the cmdlet's `-Path` parameter, i.e. the input path):

```
# Get the runspace's file-system location.
string currentDir = CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem").ProviderPath;

# .NET Core ONLY: Resolve the given path to a full path as a native path.
#                 relative to the given base path.
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Path, currentDir);
```

In *Windows PowerShell* more work is needed:

```
# Get the runspace's file-system location as a native path.
string currentDir = CurrentProviderLocation("FileSystem").ProviderPath;

# Requires `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`
# Strips a ".\" or "./" prefix from a relative path.
string relativePathWithoutPrefix = Regex.Replace(Path, @"^.[\\/]", "")

# Caveat: Combine() will not resolve any additional, *interior* . 
#         or .. components, should they be present in relativePathWithoutPrefix.
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDir, relativePathWithoutPrefix);
```

Both methods will pass a `Path` value that already *is* a full path through.

Note:

- The resulting path is by design a *native* file-system path, even if the runspace's current file-system location is based on a *PowerShell-only* drive (created with `New-PSDrive`).
- The approach implies that your cmdlet supports *file-system* paths only.

For information about how to work with PS provider locations more generally, including wildcard resolution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723810/45375).

---

<sup>[1] This discrepancy is an unfortunate side effect of PowerShell supporting *multiple runspaces* (threads) inside a *single process*, all of which need to have their own current location - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3428) for background information.</sup>

<sup>[2] For instance, the runspace's current location may be a *registry* location such as `HKCU:\Console`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It also works even if path is an absolute path because the `Path.Combine()` function manages it. Too bad there's nothing builtin `System.Management.Automation` to manage path expansion though.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Chris. There is [`System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(<path>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.getresolvedproviderpathfrompspath), as demonstrated in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723810/45375), but it it invariably uses whatever provider underlies the runspace's current location, which may or may not be the file-system provider.

Comment: Ah yes, for my purpose it will always be the file system, no registry or other provider so I will stick to your answer.